# Render a div on the right and keep the nav centered

Tags: html, css

I would like to render a `nav` and a `div` containing several buttons on the same "line" by getting the `nav` centered. However, I can not get a satisfying result. If I put my `div` after the `nav`, the `div` is displayed on the right side but under the `nav`, in part due to the following `CSS` statements:

```
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%
    background: #333;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If I remove the `header` `width` attribute and make the `nav` `float` to the `left`, then I lose the centered position of my `nav`.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class='header'>
  <div class='header-content'>
    <div class='welcome-div'>
      <h1>
        Hello
      </h1>
      <header>
        <nav id='drop-down-menu'>
          <div class="button"></div>
          <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='#'>HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>PRODUCTS</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#'>BIO</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>VIDEO</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>GALLERY</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class='lang'>
        <a class='hover-fade'>Français</a> 
        <a class='hover-fade'>English</a> 
        <a class='hover-fade'>日本語</a> 
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='clear'/>
```

The `CSS` one:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%
    background: #333;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#drop-down-menu, 
#drop-down-menu ul, 
#drop-down-menu ul li, 
#drop-down-menu ul li a, 
#drop-down-menu 
#head-mobile {
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
}

#drop-down-menu:after, 
#drop-down-menu > ul:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0
}

#drop-down-menu 
#head-mobile {
    display: none
}

#drop-down-menu {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #333
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#drop-down-menu > ul {
    text-align: center;
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li > a {
    padding: 17px;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li:hover > a, 
#drop-down-menu ul li.active a {
    color: #fff
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li:hover, 
#drop-down-menu ul li.active:hover, 
#drop-down-menu ul li.active, 
#drop-down-menu ul li.has-sub.active:hover {
    background: #448D00 !important;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: background .3s ease;
    transition: background .3s ease;
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
    padding-right: 30px
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 11px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #ddd;
    content: ''
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 14px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #ddd;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
    top: 23px;
    height: 0
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li {
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    background: #333;
    transition: all .25s ease
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li:hover {

}

#drop-down-menu li:hover > ul {
    left: auto
}

#drop-down-menu li:hover > ul > li {
    height: 35px
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul ul {
    margin-left: 100%;
    top: 0
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.15);
    padding: 11px 15px;
    width: 170px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li:last-child > a, 
#drop-down-menu ul ul li.last-item > a {
    border-bottom: 0
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li:hover > a, 
#drop-down-menu ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 11px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #ddd;
    content: ''
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    right: 14px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #ddd;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
    top: 17px;
    height: 0
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li.has-sub:hover, 
#drop-down-menu ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover {
    background: #363636;
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul ul li.active a {
    border-left: 1px solid #333
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a, 
#drop-down-menu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a {
    border-top: 1px solid #333
}

.hover-fade:hover, .hover-fade:focus, .hover-fade:active {
    background-color: #2098D1;
    color: white;
}

.hover-fade {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
    transition-property: color, background-color;
    margin: .1em;
    padding: .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
    font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 1200px;
    background-color: #111;
}

.header {
    float: left;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
}

.header-content {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.welcome-div {
    text-align: center;
}

.welcome-div h1 {
    padding: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 46px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.lang {
    float: right;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.content {
    padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60%;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.box h1 {
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
    font-family: 'Graduate', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #448D00;  
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

And a [JSFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/8pc0nc1n/5/).

I would like to keep the same layout, but with the 3 buttons aligned with the `nav`.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely position your `lang` block in top right of `header`:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%
    background: #333;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#drop-down-menu, 
#drop-down-menu ul, 
#drop-down-menu ul li, 
#drop-down-menu ul li a, 
#drop-down-menu 
#head-mobile {
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
}

#drop-down-menu:after, 
#drop-down-menu > ul:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0
}

#drop-down-menu 
#head-mobile {
    display: none
}

#drop-down-menu {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #333
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#drop-down-menu > ul {
    text-align: center;
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li > a {
    padding: 17px;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li:hover > a, 
#drop-down-menu ul li.active a {
    color: #fff
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li:hover, 
#drop-down-menu ul li.active:hover, 
#drop-down-menu ul li.active, 
#drop-down-menu ul li.has-sub.active:hover {
    background: #448D00 !important;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: background .3s ease;
    transition: background .3s ease;
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
    padding-right: 30px
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 11px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #ddd;
    content: ''
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 14px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #ddd;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
    top: 23px;
    height: 0
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li {
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    background: #333;
    transition: all .25s ease
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li:hover {

}

#drop-down-menu li:hover > ul {
    left: auto
}

#drop-down-menu li:hover > ul > li {
    height: 35px
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul ul {
    margin-left: 100%;
    top: 0
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.15);
    padding: 11px 15px;
    width: 170px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li:last-child > a, 
#drop-down-menu ul ul li.last-item > a {
    border-bottom: 0
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li:hover > a, 
#drop-down-menu ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 11px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #ddd;
    content: ''
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    right: 14px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #ddd;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
    top: 17px;
    height: 0
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul li.has-sub:hover, 
#drop-down-menu ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover {
    background: #363636;
}

#drop-down-menu ul ul ul li.active a {
    border-left: 1px solid #333
}

#drop-down-menu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a, 
#drop-down-menu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a {
    border-top: 1px solid #333
}

.hover-fade:hover, .hover-fade:focus, .hover-fade:active {
    background-color: #2098D1;
    color: white;
}

.hover-fade {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
    transition-property: color, background-color;
    margin: .1em;
    padding: .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
    font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 1200px;
    background-color: #111;
}

.header {
    float: left;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
}

.header-content {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.welcome-div {
    text-align: center;
}

.welcome-div h1 {
    padding: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 46px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.content {
    padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60%;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.box h1 {
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
    font-family: 'Graduate', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #448D00;  
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.lang {
    padding: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>
  <div class='header-content'>
    <div class='welcome-div'>
      <h1>
        Hello
      </h1>
      <header>
        <nav id='drop-down-menu'>
          <div class="button"></div>
          <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='#'>HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>PRODUCTS</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                  <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#'>BIO</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>VIDEO</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>GALLERY</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class='lang'>
        <a class='hover-fade'>Français</a> 
        <a class='hover-fade'>English</a> 
        <a class='hover-fade'>日本語</a> 
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='clear'/>
```

Comment: Your solution only works when the difference between body's width and menu's width is bigger than the double of lang menu's width. If it's not, the two menus overlap. Besides, the lang menu is not vertically centered with the main menu. So when the menu will wrap, the lang menu will remain aligned to top. It would have been better to advise on the responsiveness problem of the current layout, and possibly provide a flexbox based solution, that could degrade gracefully on narrow screens. Overall, your solution is a quick-fix, without touching the real problems of the current layout.

Comment: Please remember on [so] the purpose is to help future readers as well, not only the OP. This is not a *"fix this for me for free, please"* type of community. We strive to provide quality solutions that apply regardless of current example's content. The emphasis should be on explaining the principle and why the solution works and what are advantages of using a method over the other. I made these comments with the intention of helping you provide better answers, of which I'm sure you can and are willing to.